# PySpark DataFrame - Filter nested column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there but I haven't found any that matches my scenario exactly so please don't be *too* trigger-happy with the Duplicate flag. I'm working in a Python 3 notebook in Azure Databricks with Spark 3.0.1.

*I have the following DataFrame*

```
+---+---------+--------+
|ID |FirstName|LastName|
+---+---------+--------+
|1  |John     |Doe     |
|2  |Michael  |        |
|3  |Angela   |Merkel  |
+---+---------+--------+
```

*Which can be created with this code*

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data2 = [(1,"John","Doe"),
    (2,"Michael",""),
    (3,"Angela","Merkel")
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("ID",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("FirstName",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("LastName",StringType(),True), \
  ])
 
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df1.printSchema()
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

*I transform it into this DataFrame*

```
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|ID |Names                                    |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|1  |[[FirstName, John], [LastName, Doe]]     |
|2  |[[FirstName, Michael], [LastName, ]]     |
|3  |[[FirstName, Angela], [LastName, Merkel]]|
+---+-----------------------------------------+
```

*Using this code*

```
df2 = df1.select(
            'ID', 
            F.array(
                F.struct(
                    F.lit('FirstName').alias('NameType'), 
                    F.col('FirstName').alias('Name')
                ), 
                F.struct(
                    F.lit('LastName').alias('NameType'), 
                    F.col('LastName').alias('Name')
                )
            ).alias('Names')
        )

df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Now, I'm trying to filter out the `Names` where the `LastName` is null or is an empty string.
My overall goal is to have an object that can be serialized in json where `Names` with an empty `Name` value are excluded.

*Like this*

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Names": [
            {
                "NameType": "FirstName",
                "Name": "John"
            },
            {
                "NameType": "LastName",
                "Name": "Doe"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Names": [
            {
                "NameType": "FirstName",
                "Name": "Michael"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Names": [
            {
                "NameType": "FirstName",
                "Name": "Angela"
            },
            {
                "NameType": "LastName",
                "Name": "Merkel"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

*I have tried*

```
df2 = df1.select(
            'ID', 
            F.array(
                F.struct(
                    F.lit('FirstName').alias('NameType'), 
                    F.col('FirstName').alias('Name')
                ), 
                F.struct(
                    F.lit('LastName').alias('NameType'), 
                    F.col('LastName').alias('Name')
                )
            ).filter(lambda x: x.col('LastName').isNotNull()).alias('Names')
        )
```

but I get the error `'Column' object is not callable`.

I have also tried `df2 = df2.filter(F.col('Names')['LastName']) > 0)` but that gives me an `invalid syntax` error.

I have tried

```
df2 = df2.filter(lambda x: (len(x)>0), F.col('Names')['LastName'])
```

but that give the error `TypeError: filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

Can someone please advise me on how to get this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the higher-order function `filter`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df3 = df2.withColumn(
    'Names', 
    F.expr("filter(Names, x -> case when x.NameType = 'LastName' and length(x.Name) = 0 then false else true end)")
)

df3.show(truncate=False)
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|ID |Names                                    |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|1  |[[FirstName, John], [LastName, Doe]]     |
|2  |[[FirstName, Michael]]                   |
|3  |[[FirstName, Angela], [LastName, Merkel]]|
+---+-----------------------------------------+
```